# What happens to State in parent when the child is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In `props` I pass to the child State with Parent

This solution is two-sided. A change in one of them causes a change in the other?

**What happens to State in Parent when the child is unmounted?**

When unmounting, State returns to initialization, i.e. to an empty list. Does it affect Parent?

```
function MyParentComponent(props) {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        // Set data to info
    }, [info]);

    return (
        <View>
            <MyChild myInfo={info} />
        </View>
    );
};

function MyChild(props) {
    const { myInfo } = props || {};

    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        // Set data to info
    }, [myInfo]);

    return (
        <View>
            <View>{info[0]}</View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

**App.js**

```
function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Main' component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <MainStackNavigator />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Props are immutable/[read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). Child unmounts. Parent maintains state they have.

Comment: I have a situation that when the child is unmounted, the State in parent reinitializes. Why is this happening? When it needs values from State, it is empty

Comment: You're not conditionally rendering the child component in your example, so likely if *it* unmounted it's because the parent also unmounted/remounted for some reason.

Comment: What could be the reason that the main component will be unmounted and mounted? I created a function to initialize and added console.log (). When I look at the results, it is sometimes reinitialized. I don't know where to look for the reason

Comment: What is rendering `MyParentComponent`? Can you create an expo snack (or codesandbox) that reproduces this issue?

Comment: It's hard to add something. Speaking of the main component before, I meant Main (I added the code from App.js). In the component tree, it is not the main component. Does it matter? If I don't want to use Redux, where should I have the main data in State? In App?